# Forbidden minors for bounded genus graphs

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-minor, algebraic-topology

It is well known that $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ are forbidden minors for planar graphs. There are hundreds of forbidden minors for [graphs embeddable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_embedding) on a torus. The number of forbidden [minors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28graph_theory%29) for graphs embeddable on surface of [genus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_%28mathematics%29) *g* is an exponential function of *g*. My question is as follows :

> Is there an explicit graph $G_t$ on *t* vertices (which is not a complete graph) such that $G_t$ is a forbidden minor for graphs embeddable on surface of genus *g*, where *t* is a function of *g* ?

EDIT : I realized that the following theorem is known :

> For every surface Σ there exists an integer *r* such that $K_{3,r}$ does not embed in Σ.

So, I am looking for $G_t$ that is not complete graph, not a complete bipartite graph.

Comment: So, you want a nicely-constructed, parameterized, infinite family of graphs (other than complete graphs) that are forbidden minors for surfaces of every genus?

Comment: @Derrick. Yes. Precisely.

Comment: Then I would rephrase the question using those terms: "Is there a (simple to construct) family of graphs $\{ H_g : g \geq 1\}$ so that $H_g \not\cong K_n$ is a minimal forbidden minor for graphs embeddable on a genus $g$ surface?"

Comment: The "$K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ are not minors of $G$" constraint can't be what you want. If they are not minors of $G$, then $G$ is planar, and can't be a forbidden minor for any higher genus.

Comment: @DavidEppstein I removed my modifications. Essentially, I am looking for obstructions that are "different" from $K_5$ and $K_{33}$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The disjoint union of $n$ copies of $K_5$ (or $K_{3,3}$) is a minimal forbidden minor for the graphs of genus $n-1$; the same is true for a graph in which some of these copies share a single vertex, so that the blocks of the graph are $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$. This follows from results in J. Battle, F. Harary, Y. Kodama and J.W.T. Youngs, "Additivity of the genus of a graph", *Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.* 68 (1962) 565–568, and is already enough to show that there are at least exponentially many forbidden minors.

Bojan Mohar, "An obstruction to embedding graphs in surfaces", *Discrete Math.* 78 (1989) 135–142, lists the graph formed from $K_8$ by removing a 4-cycle as having genus 2. Since $K_7$ is toroidal, this means that either $K_8\setminus C_4$ or one of its spanning subgraphs is an obstruction to torus embedding, and that graphs that have $n$ copies of this graph as their blocks have genus $2n$.

Mohar also shows that the graph formed from a $(2k+2)$-cycle by connecting vertex 0 to all the even vertices and vertex 1 to all the odd vertices has "relative genus" at least $\lceil k/2\rceil$. The graph is planar, but I think relative genus means that the cycle has to be a face; or you could add another vertex to the graph, connected to all of the cycle vertices, to effectively force it to be a face. Maybe this is closer to the sort of thing you want. But I don't think he shows that these graphs are minimal forbidden minors.

Comment: Your last paragraph about $(2k+2)$ cycle is what I am looking for. Thanks. I am accepting your answer.