# Treewidth of deep Sierpiński Sieve Graph

Tags: treewidth

[Note $S_n$ the Sierpiński sieve graph of order $n$, which is obtained from the connectivity of the Sierpiński sieve.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SierpinskiSieveGraph.html)

[image: S_n]

For $n$ high enough, what is the treewidth of $S_n$?

I think that I can show that it is at least $4$ (by obtaining $K_5$ as a graph minor), and that it is at most $5$ (by obtained a tree-decomposition scheme involving bags of size $6$). My gut feeling is that it should be $5$, but I cannot find a proper database for forbidden minors at treewidth $4$ (and I can't access Sanders' thesis mentioned [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9008/forbidden-minors-for-bounded-treewidth-graphs)).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can recursively decompose each triangle into a smaller triangle and a trapezoid, and each trapezoid into two smaller triangles. The corresponding tree decomposition (whose bags contain the corners of a triangle at one level of the decomposition and a triangle or trapezoid at the next or previous level) has five vertices per bag and therefore has width four.

There is no $K_5$ minor, because the graph is planar. There is, however, a $K_{2,2,2}$ (octahedron) minor (actually, a subdivision), shown below. As this is one of the [forbidden minors for treewidth three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth#Forbidden_minors), the width is four.

[image]

Comment: Nice figure @David Eppstein. How did you draw it?

Comment: Adobe Illustrator, mostly using their click, drag and snap copying operation to repeatedly triple a single equilateral triangle.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! I should have realized that there can't be a $K_5$ since it is planar...